# JS Cascade code not working for SPO document library edit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document-library, jquery, cascading

I have a document library setup with content type enabled in SharePoint online. There are total 4 content types and out of those 4, for content type called 'Closing Documents', I want to perform cascading.

There are two choice dropdowns available under Closing Documents content type:
The parent is called 'TPHub DocType' (first dd) and child is 'Closing DocType' (second DD).

Now based on the choice selected in TPHub DocType, I would like to hide/show certain choices in the Closing DocType column, I do not want to leverage SPServices, just basic JS to achieve this, So I am using the code below.

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    tpcascade();
});

function tpcascade(){



$("select[title='TPHub DocType']").change(function() {
        var tphubdoctype = $("select[title='TPHub DocType']").val();
        switch(tphubdoctype){
           case 'Organizational Documents of the Fund':

$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Limited Liability Company Agreement")').hide();
//Similar to above statement, I added 136 more hide statements

$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Operating Agreement")').show();
$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Good Standing Certificate")').show(); 
$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Certificate of Formation")').show();

    break;

case 'Organizational Documents of Fund Manager':

$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Limited Liability Company Agreement")').hide();
//Similar to above statement, I added 136 more hide statements

$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("ByLaws")').show(); 
$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Resolutions")').show(); 
$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Articles of Incorporation")').show();
$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Incumbency Certificate")').show(); 
$("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Transaction Specific NMTC Delegation")').show(); 


    break;


        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Output for Org docs of the fund: (first case statement)
[image]

Output for second case statement:

[image]

FYI, wrap and unwrap are showing the exact same behavior as hide and show.For each case first I am adding all 137 choices to hide them first and then respectively show choices based on case value. Output of first statement is simply off, you can see, I have only enabled show for 3 choices and dropdon shows other values. ANy thoughts?
For some reason, the code does not work. Can someone help me correct it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using the code mentioned [here](http://www.markrackley.net/2014/05/20/cascading-drop-down-lists-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-rest/) by Mark Rackley, its using REST, easy to setup and works great, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    cascade();
});
function cascade(){
    $("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Operating Agreement")').wrap('<span/>');
    $("select[title='TPHub DocType']").change(function() {
        var tphubdoctype = $("select[title='TPHub DocType']").val();
        switch(tphubdoctype){
            case 'Organizational Documents of the Fund':        
                $("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("ByLaws")').wrap('<span/>');
                $("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Resolutions")').wrap('<span/>');
            break;
            case 'Organizational Documents of Fund Manager':
                $("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("ByLaws")').unwrap(); 
                $("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Operating Agreement")').unwrap();
                $("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Certificate of Formation")').wrap('<span/>');
            break;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: The code no longer works now, I updated the script I am using based on your answer, please check and let me know if anything is wrong,

Comment: I have total of 137 different choice values in closing doctype column, for which I am writing wrap and unwrap, is there a limitation size wise?

Comment: Check my code above, you need wrap the choice value before unwrap it.  $("select[title='Closing DocType']").find('option:contains("Operating Agreement")').wrap('<span/>');

Comment: The thing is in my case, TPHub Doctype column has 20 choice values and Closing DocType has 137 choice values. So now based on selection in TPHub Doctype column, I have to only show 3-4 choices values in Closing DocType and hide others and I am going nuts , can't get it to work.

Comment: Should I specify all 137 choices with wrap first? And then respectively unwrap for each case. One thing to mention is, there are scenarios where for two different case values, I have  to unwrap the same column value and its breaking when that happens. I think I have to leverage SPServices now.

Comment: Yes, you can wrap all choices first, then unwrap it base on the conditions.

Comment: I added more info to question description, please check. The code shows inconsistent behavior, I even tried to add all wrap statements right above .change as you showed but still no luck.